# Unable to create user or upload images in WP

Tags: wordpress

When I tried to create a new user or tried to upload images, data is getting submitted in the database and files are there in FTP. But they are not displaying in WordPress front-end. And when I tried to log in with that new user, I couldn't.

Even when I tried to delete an old user, it wasn't appearing anymore in front-end but they are still in the database.

--
I had a word with my hosting team and they said:
I tried to change the theme disabled plugins moved the site to different php versions but it did not help. It seems that the issue is with the database itself. Something modified some of the columns and they have no primary key with autoincrement which gives them a 0 ID and every user added can't be displayed in the WordPress.

Comment: You need provide the code what you did for the create user, upload imgs and what you have did to display that in the front-end. Also you need let's know what you did for login. We are not here to work on your task.

Comment: Are you uploading the images from wp-admin URL?

Comment: Aki, as I mentioned I used front-end, which I assume means WP Dashboard.
@HarijithR Yes